# Fat Jar runs in host machine but fails in Docker Container

Tags: java, docker, maven

I have fat .jar file created using Maven that runs correctly when executed on many laptops (I tried it on 3 machines) using the command

```
java -jar target/appname.jar
```

but whenever I try to dockerize it, it fails with the following error:

```
Error: unable to initialize main class mypackage.MyMainClass
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: externaljarname/src/MyOtherClass
```

I can't understand why on three different machines, that I have never used, I can run easily the .jar file but in Docker no.

More info:

The fat .jar that fails is an application that makes use of a custom library that I have created. This means, initially I had a custom Java library exported as jar, then my new project imports this Library to perform some operations.

For generating the current fat .jar, I firstly installed it using

```
mvn clean org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -Dfile="mylibrary.jar"
```

then I packaged everything:

```
mvn clean package
```

My current fat .jar, in the pom.xml, has a dependency to my library and I use the Maven Shade Plugin to generate the fat .jar as follows:

```
<plugin> 
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <executions> 
                <execution> 
                    <phase>package</phase> 
                    <goals> 
                        <goal>shade</goal> 
                    </goals> 
                    <configuration> 
                        <transformers> 
                             <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"> 
                                <mainClass>
                                    mypackage.MyMainClass
                                </mainClass> 
                            </transformer> 
                        </transformers> 
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>
                            false
                        </createDependencyReducedPom>     
                    </configuration> 
                </execution> 
            </executions> 
        </plugin>
```

Do you have any idea why this happens?

P.S: The JDK used is the 11 and the Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
MAINTAINER "Docker App <docker@app.com>"
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./target/*.jar ./app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your fat jar most likely isn’t. Go inside and investigate with the jar command.

Comment: If the answer isn't correct ( I suspect it is) you can check your manifest and look at the classpath. The classpath might reference a lib folder with more jar files that you are not including. A fat jar file should include all of the other jar files, but the way you are copying makes me suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Dockerfile you have:

```
COPY ./target/*.jar ./app.jar
```

This is (probably) copying your original jar **AND** the fat jar (`*.jar`) to /app/.

Only copy the jar you need.

Comment: This seems like the type of action that should fail. They're copying a bunch of files to a single file.

Comment: The copies are created sequentially, and all are copied to `./app.jar`, so the last one copied is `./app.jar`.

Comment: Thanks! You both were entirely correct. Indeed in the target directory I had 2 .jar files: the fat appname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and the lightweight original-appname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. I have now edited the Dockerfile not to copy ./target/*.jar but ./target/appname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and it works perfectly. Thanks again.